# Indexed UILabels Objective-C

Tags: iphone, uilabel

i am programming an iphone application and need help with the UILabels.
An example:
I have 10 Labels named Label1, Label2, Label3 etc.
and Label1.text = @"1", Label2.text=@"2" etc.
is there a way to do it in a for-loop. Like
for(int i = 1, i<11,i++){Labeli.text = ...} ?
thx for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Set tag for each label and access the value as follows,

```
for(int i=1; i<=10;i++)
{
    UILabel *lab=(UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
    [lab setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
}
```

or else do as follows,

```
NSArray *labels=[NSArray arrayWithObjects: label1, label2, nil];

int i=1;

for(UILabel *label in labels) {
  [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
  i++;
}
```

Comment: In the first block, when he sets the tag, why wouldn't he just set the text as well?

Comment: He can set diff text later na??

Answer (score 0):

Here's the proper for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numLabels; i++) {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
    // other label customizations here
    [myMutableArray addObject:label]
    [label release];
}
```

Then, later, access each label with `[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:index];`